# CPU getting stuck during boot due to nvidia driver

Tags: boot, drivers, 16.04, nvidia, gpu

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on my desktop and it seems the boot is delayed by the nvidia driver in this line of dmesg: `[   32.227060] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 23s! [nvidia-smi:2958]`

The Machine runs Linux Kernel 4.8.15 and the latest nvidia drivers 375.26 on a GTX 970.

dmesg output: http://pastebin.com/e5memf0e

systemd-analyze: `Startup finished in 8.588s (firmware) + 1.275s (loader) + 3.057s (kernel) + 45.268s (userspace) = 58.190s`

systemd-analyze blame: http://pastebin.com/AxVF41xL

What could be the cause of this issue? How could it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You must add "nouveau.modeset=0" to the grub at the end of the line that starts with "linux". To do it you need to press e to edit in the grub menu and after the line update you press F10 to boot.

Install the right NVidia drivers at the end.

Comment: This will not nessecerally fix this.